# In BigQuery, is there any way to avoid query processing costs?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to avoid the processing cost in BigQuery when creating a table from a query result e.g:

```
select *  from xxx where ....
```

...and write into a destination table.

Is there a way to do it using one of the BigQuery tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Whenever you query, you will be pay for how much data you are touching in the query no matter what.

Remember, your first 1TB p/m is free in BigQuery. So maybe this is not really a problem for you.

Comment: it does matter, my data set is around 900 TB :) (look back on the past 90 days)

Comment: OK, but that doesn't change the fact that the answer is still "No" - you cannot avoid the processing costs.

Comment: ye, I got it.
Thanks

Comment: Your dataset is 900 TB, nice! You should really partition it into smaller tables, or use the new `partitioned tables` feature: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables